# Why would media_sideload_image() not work locally?

Tags: uploads, media, post-editor

I designed a theme for a client that sideloads an image returned from an API. It has always worked and it's still working on their live website.

My staging environment *used* to be a separate account on the same server. It was accessible online but password-protected and sideloading images always worked there as well. Today I created a local staging environment using VirtualHostX. Everything on the website works as expected, *but sideloading doesn't.*

- Nothing in my source has changed.
- The WordPress installation is a direct clone (configuration and build numbers are identical)
- I've verified that my AJAX response is returning an image URL, but the image doesn't even make it into the media library.

Before I spend too much time diagnosing this I thought I'd ask the obvious: is there a reason `media_sideload_image()` wouldn't work locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is silly, but it turns out there was a **very** obvious reason why `media_sideload_image()` wasn't working. My `wp-content` folder had the wrong the permissions from when I transferred it to my local environment and I wasn't able to upload anything. Changed the permissions and it's working fine.